# SOAP http binding example

Tags: web-services, soap

I am trying to understand soap http binding. I was under the impression that when using jax-ws, I am always sending any request to the server inside soap envelope and getting a soap response.

But reading about soap1.2 support of http binding for GET and POST, I see that one can describe the webservice in wsdl with http bindings, and the service request and response are returned in simple xml document.

In the following webService of stockpricequote, the webservice can be accessed by Soap 1.1, Soap 1.2, HTTP get and HTTP post

http://www.visualwebservice.com/wsdl/ws.cdyne.com/delayedstockquote.asmx%3Fwsdl

Can somebody point me to a Web Service example with code For Soap http binding, where I can request and receive response without SOAP header ?

Answer (score -2):

You can find an example here: http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/default.asp

Comment: w3school does not have an example of a web service request. Also, the http binding example shows SOAP request and response. I was looking for an example similar to the webservice shown in my post.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but the only request you should perform is generic HTTP POST. Check here: http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/ws_use.asp
Result is pure XML.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, you are right that HTTP POST is returning pure XML. I am not sure if that webservice example is WS-I compliant. Also, I am not very familiar with asp.net. Can you point me to an example using jax-ws ?

Comment: I have no experience of creation services HTTP binding with JAX-WS, may be you just need to create a service as usual and simply use appropriate annotation: @BindingType(value = HTTPBinding.HTTP_BINDING). You can also use Axis2 to create service with HTTP binding. Axis2 POJO services are pretty simple to create.